# Facebook Instant game purchase issue

Tags: facebook, in-app-purchase, game-engine, facebook-instant-games, cocoscreator

I am integrating InApp purchases in my game(build using cocos creator). but unable to get payments.purchaseAsync   in  FBInstant.getSupportedAPIs() on both Android And Facebook.com any Help please below is the my sample code.

```
let supportedAPIs = FBInstant.getSupportedAPIs();
      if(supportedAPIs.includes('payments.purchaseAsync'))
      {
          console.log('payments supported...');

          FBInstant.payments.onReady(() => {
              console.log('payments ready...');
              FBInstant.payments.purchaseAsync({
                  productID: 'com.test.testing',
                  developerPayload: '',
              }).then(function (purchase) {
                  console.log(purchase);
              });
          });
      }
      else
      {
          console.log('payments not supported...');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your game must be onboarded and have a company associated with it in order for payments to be enabled. You can ensure that this is set up by clicking **Set Up Payout** under the **In App Purchase** option under the developer console (developers.facebook.com).

[image: Set Up Payout option depicted on developers.facebook.com]

In addition, you will need to have passed review for users who are not developers or testers of the app to access payments, and payments are not available on iOS at this time.